# Laravel is returning different data types in axios with same code

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, response, axios

I am really confused about my situation right now.
As you can see I have this controller in laravel that separates the data from a collection by filtering the collection

```
 $bankedQuestions = $questions->whereNotIn('id', $sortedQuestionsID)->all();
 $sortedQuestions = $questions->whereIn('id', $sortedQuestionsID)->all();
```

Everything works great and it both returns an array, checked it using dd(); then, I return it as a json

```
return response()->json([
   'message' => 'Question loaded',
  'sortedQuestions' => $sortedQuestions,
  'questions' => $bankedQuestions,
  'sortedIDs' => $sortedQuestionsID,
]);
```

THEN the confusing part comes into place. When I check the axios response the data types are very very different.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening guys? I've been checking the data and the parameters and everything are as expected. I'm using vueJS with Axios and Laravel.

Raw response:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the raw JSON?

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz what do you mean by raw JSON?

Comment: Well, your Laravel code returns a JSON response. You're showing us the JavaScript console log, but I'd like to see the actual JSON from the Network tabl.

Comment: here you go

{,…}
6
:
{id: 12, smart_script_id: "1", smart_script_question_id: null, external_id: "A1", name: "Section 7",…}
7
:
{id: 13, smart_script_id: "1", smart_script_question_id: null, external_id: "3125", name: "Section 8",…}
8
:
{id: 14, smart_script_id: "1", smart_script_question_id: null, external_id: "123", name: "Section 9",…}
9
:
{id: 15, smart_script_id: "1", smart_script_question_id: null, external_id: "asd", name: "Section 10",…}

Comment: I just went with what I got. but would love to know why this was happening though.

Comment: That JSON doesn't match the code you're showing. Your API call should be returning something that looks along the lines of `{
    "message": "Question loaded",
    "sortedQuestions": [{}, {}, {}],
    "questions": [{}, {}, {}],
    "sortedIDs": [...]
}` -  we need to see that output. You should edit it into your question instead of as a comment.

Comment: Updated it @ceejayoz

Comment: Not the JavaScript `console.log` output of the *parsed* JSON. The raw JSON. Go to the Network tab in your inspector, that's where it'll be.